# PostGIS 3D Extrude function

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, 3d

I selected buildings from OSM (which represents my city). I insterted a new column 'height' and I filled with a random number exactly number 2, so every building have 2metres altitude. Buildings are in 4326 and these are stored in the geom field. I would like to extrude all building with the ST_Extrude function.

I tried : SELECT gid, ST_Extrude(geom, 0,0, height) as geom
FROM csong_buildings;

not working:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by not working?  You mean it gives an unexpected result or it errors out?